# Differentiability of two variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Is $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\cfrac{x^3+x\sqrt{y^4+y^5}}{x^2+y^2}, &(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 
0, &(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$ differentiable at $(x,y)=(0,0)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to get you started: Note that $f(x,0)=x$, while $f(0,y)=0$. From this you can compute the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$, and conclude that the linear approximation, if it holds, is simply $x$. So look at $f(x,y)-x$ and see if it is small enough as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ to satisfy the definition of differentiability.